# Query variable does not work

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch data with two queries.In the first query, I get page_id from the page table.After fetching, Page id second query is running. But in when I passed first query variable in the second query then it's not working.

```
<?php
     $getvideo = "select page_id from pages";
     $resu = mysql_query($getvideo);
     $i = 1;
     while ($video = mysql_fetch_array($resu)){
           $page_id = $video['page_id']; 
     }
     $getvideo = "select * from pages where active='1' and page_category='What-we-do' and page_id='$page_id' order by add_date desc limit 7";

     $resu = mysql_query($getvideo);
     $i = 1;
     while ($video = mysql_fetch_array($resu)) :
         // print_r($video);
         $videos = $video['image'];
         $url = $video['url'];
         $alt = $video['img_alt'];
         $alt = $video['page_id'];
         //echo  $page_id = $video['page_id'];
         echo $rel_blog = $video['rel_blog'];
         ?>
         <div data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="0" data-aos-duration="1000" data-aos-once="true" class="col-md-4 text-center">
         <img src="<?= $SiteUrl; ?>upload/pages/<?= $videos ?>" alt="<?= $alt ?>" title="<?= $alt ?>" class="mx-auto" />
         <h4 style="line-height:23px">
         <?= $video['page_title']; ?></h4>
         <p><?= $video['page_content']; ?></p>
         </div>
         <?php endwhile; ?>       
         </div>
         </div>
         </div>
         </div>
```

Comment: How does those tables look like? Also, in the first block of code, you have a space before the `$page_id` in the query. In addition, look up how to prepare and bind in mysqli and stop the use of mysql functions. They are deprecated

Comment: Just why are you still using `mysql_*` functions?  It's 2018. Didn't you get the memo?  Either use pdo or mysqli

Comment: Akintunde007@hey its not new project all function working as a mysql so  sudden i can not change as a mysqli right now .please help me

Comment: ezw@this is old project and so  mysql function is used each and every where @ please help me regarding to solve my problem

Comment: Akintunde007@select * from pages where active='1' and page_category='What-we-do' and page_id=' $page_id' order by add_date desc limit 7"  does not work because  while loop is closed before  so $page_title does not receive any value  in this query , any help

Comment: How does those tables look like? Feels like you need to do some joining instead of what you are doing here

Comment: ezw @My While loop is closing before  my second sql query so $page_id does not receive any value so its not working

Comment: @webduniya the last `$page_id` is still set so it should retrieve it's info no matter if the while is closed or not. You have a space in front of the `$page_id` which would make MySQL to try and retreive `' 296'` instead of `'296'`. Are you even reading the comments?

Comment: ezw@i updated my question  in easy away please check this

Comment: @webduniya So you want to retrieve all pages with the first while loop and then all info for those pages with the second while loop?

Comment: ezw@i do not know where is  I am wrong , this query is working on  sql cli,but here it's not working

Comment: ezw @my query is same I want fetch page_id first , then  in second query I want fetch all  information of page, please help

Comment: Why are you retrieving the page_id first and then the info? Retrieve everything at once and then do an `if ... else` condition on page IDs to display what you want

Comment: ezw@please provide me solution ,help me if its possible like this

Comment: ezw@I am fetching page_id first because my  landing page need data according to page id

Comment: ezw@you there?please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I found answer for this question. for  get variable outside of loop we have to define blank variable outside of loop. this is work perfect for me .

```
<?php

        $getvideo = "select page_id from pages";
        $resu = mysql_query($getvideo);
 $page_id=""
        $i = 1;
        while ($video = mysql_fetch_array($resu)){
        $page_id.= $video['page_id']; 
  }
        $getvideo = "select * from pages where active='1' and page_category='What-we-do' and page_id='$page_id' order by add_date desc limit 7";

        $resu = mysql_query($getvideo);
        $i = 1;
        while ($video = mysql_fetch_array($resu)) :
            // print_r($video);
            $videos = $video['image'];
            $url = $video['url'];
            $alt = $video['img_alt'];
            $alt = $video['page_id'];
            //echo  $page_id = $video['page_id'];
            echo $rel_blog = $video['rel_blog'];
            ?>
                 <div data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="0" data-aos-duration="1000" data-aos-once="true" class="col-md-4 text-center">
                    <img src="<?= $SiteUrl; ?>upload/pages/<?= $videos ?>" alt="<?= $alt ?>" title="<?= $alt ?>" class="mx-auto" />
                    <h4 style="line-height:23px">
                            <?= $video['page_title']; ?></h4>
                    <p><?= $video['page_content']; ?></p>
                </div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>


 </div>
</div>
    </div>
     </div>
```